# pick a specific contour level in seaborn/matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, contour

I have a dataset with x and y variables. I plotted them in a regular plot:[image]

Now I want to plot the contour level of the density probability contour level eg: 50% of the values are in this area. I tried with seaborn with the following code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# define my x an y axes
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.randn(100)
y = np.random.randn(100)


# Create a joint plot with scatter plot and KDE contour lines
sns.jointplot(x = x, y = y, kind = "scatter", color = 'b')
sns.kdeplot(x = x, y = y, color = "r", levels = 5)
plt.ylim(0, 17.5)
plt.xlim(0, 20)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

and the result is:
[image]

But I would like to choose the contour level values. I searched a long time for a solution but didn't find any really… Is there a simple way of doing this ?

Comment: Does `levels=[0.5]` not work?

Comment: Ah wow it was that easy ^^well thank you I couldn't find it anywhere

Comment: Do you know too how I can print the number on the contour levels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure that contour labelling is directly accessible in `seaborn`. `matplotlib` has a `clabel` function that adds labels to contours. I've wrapped it in a function `overlay_labelled_contours()` that overlays contours onto your existing scatter plot's axis.

The data + code below shows how you can get labelled contours at different quantiles (similar to seaborn's `kdeplot(levels=...`).

[image]

Imports and data:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# define x and y axes
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.randn(1000)
y = x + np.random.randn(1000) - 0.5
```

Overlay contours:

```py
# Create a joint plot with scatter plot and KDE contour lines
g = sns.jointplot(x=x, y=y, marker='.', kind="scatter", color='tab:brown')
overlay_labelled_contours(x, y, ax=g.figure.axes[0])

plt.gcf().set_size_inches(7, 4)
plt.gca().set(xlabel='x', ylabel='y')
```

Function that handles the contours:

```py
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

def overlay_labelled_contours(
    x, y, ax, lims=None, quantile_levels=[0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.8],
    bw_method=0.5, cmap='copper', text_color=None
):
    # Fit KDE estimator on the data
    data_coords = np.column_stack([x, y])
    kde_estimator = gaussian_kde(
        dataset=data_coords.T,
        bw_method=bw_method
    )
    kde_data_scores = kde_estimator.evaluate(data_coords.T).T

    # Define a fine grid and get the map of kde scores
    grid_res = 200
    if not lims:
        lims = [x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()]
    x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(
        np.linspace(lims[0], lims[1], num=grid_res),
        np.linspace(lims[2], lims[3], num=grid_res)
    )
    kde_grid_scores = kde_estimator.evaluate(
        np.column_stack([x_grid.ravel(), y_grid.ravel()]).T
    ).T
    
    # Convert the KDE density scores to a quantile score
    scores_sorted = np.sort(kde_data_scores)
    scores_cdf = [(kde_data_scores < thresh).mean() for thresh in scores_sorted]
    
    gridscores_as_cdf = np.interp(kde_grid_scores, scores_sorted, scores_cdf)
    one_minus_cdf = 1 - gridscores_as_cdf
    
    # add KDE quantile lines
    c = ax.contour(
        x_grid, y_grid, one_minus_cdf.reshape(x_grid.shape),
        cmap=cmap, levels=quantile_levels, linewidths=3
    )
    # label the contours
    if not text_color:
        text_color = 'black'
    
    ax.clabel(c, fontsize=12, colors=text_color)
```

---

**How it works**

The x and y data coordinates are first organised into a two-column matrix shaped `n_samples x 2`:

```py
    data_coords = np.column_stack([x, y])
```

A KDE model is fitted on that data (it needs the data as `2 x n_samples`, so we supply the transpose of the data matrix):

```py
    kde_estimator = gaussian_kde(
        dataset=data_coords.T,
        bw_method=bw_method
    )
```

After fitting the KDE, we get the density estimates at the data points:

```py
    kde_data_scores = kde_estimator.evaluate(data_coords.T).T
```

Since you are interested in quantiles, we map the estimated densities to data proportions. In other words, we learn a mapping that takes in a density values, and tells us what proportion of the data lies below that value. This allows us to convert density data to quantile data.

```py
    # Convert the KDE density scores to a quantile score
    scores_sorted = np.sort(kde_data_scores)
    scores_cdf = [(kde_data_scores < thresh).mean() for thresh in scores_sorted]
```

We will be drawing the contours in a 2D space, so we define a 2D grid of coordinates:

```py
    # Define a fine grid and get the map of kde scores
    grid_res = 200
    if not lims:
        lims = [x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()]
    x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(
        np.linspace(lims[0], lims[1], num=grid_res),
        np.linspace(lims[2], lims[3], num=grid_res)
    )
```

For each point on the grid, use the fitted KDE model to estimate the density at that point:

```py
    kde_grid_scores = kde_estimator.evaluate(
        np.column_stack([x_grid.ravel(), y_grid.ravel()]).T
    ).T
```

We then map those estimated densities over the entire 2D area to proportions of the data, since we want the contours to represent proportions of the data.

```py
    gridscores_as_cdf = np.interp(kde_grid_scores, scores_sorted, scores_cdf)
    one_minus_cdf = 1 - gridscores_as_cdf
```

Finally, `ax.contour` is used to display and label contours at the user-defined quantile levels.

```py
    # add KDE quantile lines
    c = ax.contour(
        x_grid, y_grid, one_minus_cdf.reshape(x_grid.shape),
        cmap=cmap, levels=quantile_levels, linewidths=3
    )
    # label the contours
    if not text_color:
        text_color = 'black'
    
    ax.clabel(c, fontsize=12, colors=text_color)
```

---

---

---

A fully-`matplotlib` approach, including histograms at the margins.

The data is plotted on a `plt.scatter` plot, with the labelled contours overlaid using `overlay_labelled_contours()`. Finally, histograms are added at the margins using `make_axes_locatable()`.

[image]

```
#
#Scatter plot with contours and marginal histograms, using matplotlib
#
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))

#Scatter x and y data
ax.scatter(x, y, marker='.', s=5, color='tab:blue')

overlay_labelled_contours(x, y, ax)

#optional formatting
[ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False) for spine in ['right', 'top']]
ax.set(xlabel='x', ylabel='y')

# Add marginal histograms
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

# New axes on top and right of "ax"
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
ax_histx = divider.append_axes('top', 0.8, pad=0.1, sharex=ax)
ax_histy = divider.append_axes('right', 0.8, pad=0.1, sharey=ax)
[axis.axis('off') for axis in [ax_histx, ax_histy]]

ax_histx.hist(x, bins=30)
ax_histy.hist(y, bins=30, orientation='horizontal')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but the numbers should be the other way around: 0.10 for the smaller circle and 0.80 for the bigger circle

Comment: Another weird thing is that when I run your Matplotlib example, the numbers of the contour levels are not plotted in black but in the contour level colors. How can I change that to black as in your last figure?

Comment: No problem. I've updated my answer. The text colour will be black unless set otherwise. I think it's working correctly now (there was calculation error in the previous version). I'd suggest inspecting the results you get with your data to ensure the values are reasonable.

Comment: Perfect, thank you ! I compared the contour levels from your function with the contours from the automatic seaborn contour levels, and they are not the same. It seems that they are fewer points included in each of your contour levels. I must say that I don't really understand your function so it's hard for me to edit it :/ As this plot is for my paper it needs to be quite exact...

Comment: Actually I have noticed something: the seaborn contour levels are not the probability to have the data point inside that region, because when I set only one contour level at 0.9, it's a very small circle that do not include 90% of the data points.. Now i'm very lost...

Comment: When you set the contour level at 0.9 in seaborn, the contour drawn would be such that 90% of the density mass is outside, and 10% is within the contour. So only a few points will be inside such a contour. Is that what you're seeing?

Comment: Does 90% of the density mass means 90% of the data points ? Actually, I would like a contour that shows 90% of the data point *inside* the contour level

Comment: Density mass suggests that seaborn has fitted a model, and the contours are for that model rather than directly for the data points. So "90% of the density mass" will be close to 90% of the actual data points, but not exactly the same. I think that the lower you set `bw_method`, the more the contours will follow the exact data, but the result will look less smooth. To get approximately 90% of points inside the contour in `kdeplot`, set the contour level to 0.10 - that means  10% wil lie below/outside the contour, and 90% will be inside the contour.

Comment: Okay I understand thank's a lot ! So now I plotted the seaborn contour level 0.05 and 0.32 (`levels = [0.05, 0.32]`) to have the 0.95 and 0.68 contour levels. I also plotted the 0.95 and 0.68 contour level with your function (`quantile_levels=[0.68, 0.95]`) but it's not exactly the same levels, the levels of your function are slightly smaller. It is normal ? Do you know why ?

Comment: No problem. I am not sure why they differ. I don't know enough about how `seaborn` works under the hood, apart from that it uses `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` which I've also used. One difference could be that I use an empirical CDF, whereas `seaborn` *might* be modelling the CDF and using the model instead.

Comment: In relation to your comment about understanding & editing the code - I've now updated the answer with explanations of the code. Happy to explain it further if required.